# How to add disable class on a button when continuous loop is disabled and slider can't move in that direction?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I would like to disable continuos loop on items and style buttons different if they can't be used.

So the first slide shouldn't be able to move to the left, and last slide shouldn't be able to move to the right. How to add disable that functionality and add class "disabled" on buttons if slide can't move in that direction?
I feel like this is a basic thing to do, I am surprised to see that Bootstrap doesn't add that automatically.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ivan-topi/pen/zYKGvpP)

```css
.carousel {
  max-width: 500px; 
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
}

.carouselcontrol {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: -100px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #333;
}

a.disable {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="true" data-interval="3000">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/310x200">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/320x200">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/330x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="carouselcontrol">
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded a simple solution with Jquery, but I stopped the auto slide for now. If you want to add auto slide you don't need anything use the same code snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slid.bs.carousel', '', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
    $('.carouselcontrol .carousel-control-next').show();
    $('.carouselcontrol .carousel-control-prev').show();

  if($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.carouselcontrol .carousel-control-prev').hide();
    console.log("prev hide");
  } else if($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:last').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.carouselcontrol .carousel-control-next').hide();
    console.log("next hide");
  }

});
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
}

.carouselcontrol {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -100px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
}

a.disable {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="true" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/310x200">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/320x200">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://place-hold.it/330x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="carouselcontrol">
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
  
</div>
```

In addition, you need the handle first slide. You don't any need previous arrow in first slide, set as `display:none` in the begining.